# Sharepoint file upload with API using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

What I want is uploading file to specific directory in the sharepoint via API and using python.

*Here is my code:*

```
import requests
from shareplum import Office365
from config_s import config_s

# get data from config_suration
username = config_s['sp_user']
password = config_s['sp_password']
site_name = config_s['sp_site_name']
base_path = config_s['sp_base_path']
doc_library = config_s['sp_doc_library']

file_name = "/Users/Metatrons/Desktop/AutoReport_Structure/test.csv"

# Obtain auth cookie
authcookie = Office365(base_path, username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = authcookie
session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'python_bite/v1'})
session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})

session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': 'FormDigestValue'})#FormDigestValue
response = session.post( url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)",
                         data="")
session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': response.headers['X-RequestDigest']})

# perform the actual upload
with open( file_name, 'rb') as file_input:
    try: 
        response = session.post( 
            url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='" 
            + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",
            data=file_input)
        print(response)
        print(response.headers)
        #print(response.headers['X-RequestDigest'])
    except Exception as err: 
        print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))
        print("What the  FUUUUUUUUUUUUCK")
```

And I got the message that

**
Response [400]

{'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 
'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 
'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8', 
'Expires': 'Mon, 27 Apr 2020 05:58:55 GMT', 
'Last-Modified': 'Tue, 12 May 2020 05:58:55 GMT', 
'P3P': 'CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"', 
'Set-Cookie': 'rtFa=v+WfHj06vOlD59P0qVwsXStksrafJI486yruddHryI0mOTk4NkVEMTItMjc3MS00RTY2LThCNUUtQTIwODBENkIyN0U3bZhIUWlknsxj7X5UIUNUvMimHWhZd/gZoFgaZg5Dr4Wm/QbeuGwyrg5iFuo9Pt5IGannrRBEyxwiSaUwPrgHhkRrlkAnf6N6+3tS7eSnl7ebzMkkIar20aS/LCZRs8Z/UNFD/pj8ptYvwspbCDNz/m/gA5tdhlURmKCeqN94Ry16SR+7KjuAFnrfNHEMYjHsh9CotruRb4jQUEQOkVNLuHIabuq3qNJLWv4CQA/JM3LHW528rf/tR64zzKHRIqfdziTzCRnndQP9+5YzMk0jFFfslLjmjvMMO19yQ1m70+T8l/qyQk5GOMkFcw3Zw9hihPpC29SDuTts46lDBVWqOkUAAAA=; domain=sharepoint.com; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly, FedAuth=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; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly', 
'X-SharePointHealthScore': '0', 
'X-SP-SERVERSTATE': 'ReadOnly=0', 
'DATASERVICEVERSION': '3.0', 
'SPClientServiceRequestDuration': '54', 
'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 
'SPRequestGuid': '3c9a519f-00ce-a000-89f2-6080347e58ff', 
'request-id': '3c9a519f-00ce-a000-89f2-6080347e58ff', 
'MS-CV': 'n1GaPM4AAKCJ8mCANH5Y/w.0', 
'X-RequestDigest': '0x26237158F71B34858BF0EB713CDA5A9412C28A5AC95FF342B326F7B8DE04DD93AA4E233004444AC0D7BF427E2D05BDA4B526CB2BF8BB32D73F8917E9CC88F495,12 May 2020 05:58:56 -0000', 
'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 
'X-FRAME-OPTIONS': 'SAMEORIGIN', 
'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 
'MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices': '16.0.0.20029', 
'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 
'X-MS-InvokeApp': '1; RequireReadOnly', 
'X-MSEdge-Ref': 'Ref A: DFB58EAF5C2D4ECB8027CD2E3348A80C Ref B: TPE30EDGE0216 Ref C: 2020-05-12T05:58:55Z', 
'Date': 'Tue, 12 May 2020 05:58:55 GMT'}
**

Plz help me to figure out this problem, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a reference of below sample, i have tested it on my SPO environment.

```
import requests
from shareplum import Office365
from config import config

# get data from configuration
username = config['sp_user']
password = config['sp_password']
site_name = config['sp_site_name']
base_path = config['sp_base_path']
doc_library = config['sp_doc_library']

file_name = "test.html"
# Obtain auth cookie
authcookie = Office365(base_path, username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = authcookie
session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'python_bite/v1'})
session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})

# dirty workaround.... I'm getting the X-RequestDigest from the first failed call
session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': 'FormDigestValue'})
response = session.post( url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + 
"/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + 
"')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)",
                     data="")
session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': response.headers['X-RequestDigest']})

# perform the actual upload
with open( r'C:\Users\mengfeik\Documents\test.html', 'rb+') as file_input:
try: 
    response = session.post( 
        url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='" 
        + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",
        data=file_input)
except Exception as err: 
    print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))

print('end...')
```

Comment: Thx, you solved my problem!
And I want to ask that I got the Response 403. 
The error message is that :

'X-Forms_Based_Auth_Return_Url': 'https://{domain}.com/_layouts/15/error.aspx', 'X-MSDAVEXT_Error': '917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.'

I don't know how to solve this problem.
I already surveyed some website for information like 
https://www.undocumented-features.com/2019/12/02/resolved-sharepoint-online-web-site-does-not-support-sharepoint-online-credentials/